# Is there a way to open h2 console while some other application is also accessing the same db?

Tags: java, h2

I am using h2 db in a java application. I am using H2 console to view the contents of db, but it only works when no other application is accessing the db.
Is there a way to open h2 console while some other application is also accessing the same db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to connect from multiple application you can configure your db to accept tcp connection. Basically, you can do that by using `jdbc:h2:tcp` in your db url.

Read more about this [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server).

Comment: There are actually two more ways: when the database is in the same process, then the embedded mode can be use; and when using the auto-server mode everywhere (see the docs)